# What is the scope of glTexParameter's in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-es, 3d

Does `glTexParamter` act on all textures globally or only the texture that is currently bound.

For example, if I call this at the texture load:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

And this on another texture load:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
```

When I bind the first texture will it just use the last value I set (`GL_CLAMP`) or will it use the values originally set when the texture was bound?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [OpenGL FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/):

---

**21.070 How do texture objects work?**

Texture objects store texture maps and their associated texture parameter state. They allow switching between textures with a single call to glBindTexture().

(...)

The following functions affect and store state in texture objects: glTexImage*(), glTexSubImage*(), glCopyTexImage*(), glCopyTexSubImage*(), **glTexParameter*()**, and glPrioritizeTextures(). Since the GLU routines for building mipmap pyramids ultimately call glTexImage*(), they also affect texture object state.Noticeably absent from this list are glTexEnv*() and glTexGen*(); they do not store state in texture objects.

---

Ergo, glTexParameter* affects only the bound texture.

Comment: Very cool that is what I was hoping otherwise I would have to do a bunch of state changes everytime I bound a texture.

Comment: @JustinMeiners In modern GL, there is `glGenSamplers` that gives you that exact thing, I think.